# Working of apache tomcat server

Tags: java

When I place my project which contains jsp and java files in the Webapp folder of apache tomcat and when i access it through browser how come i able to see all my jsp in the browser, but not without apache tomcat. So my question is what does apache tomcat really do?

Comment: you question does not make sense to me

Comment: Best way to learn any thing is spend sometime with books

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache and Tomcat are two different things.

**Apache** is a simple http server which servesyou pages when you make a request for the page.

**Tomcat** is a **web container** that deals with your servlets, jsps and their mappings.

If you make any request to apache for a servlet for a servlet or jsp, the apache will check with tomcat which in turn checks all the url mappings and generates the result in the format that browsers can interpret. After this generation the generated content is handed over to **apache** which sends you back the response and your browser displays it to you.

If you make request for simple html or image the **Apache** serves it to you without any role of tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Tomcat is a webcontainer which allows to run servlet and JavaServer Pages based web applications. Most of the modern Java web frameworks are based on servlets and JavaServer Pages and can run on Apache Tomcat, e.g. JavaServer Faces, Struts, Spring.

Apache Tomcat also provides by default a HTTP connector on port 8080, e.g. Tomcat can also be used as HTTP server even though the performance of Tomcat is not as good as the performance of the Apache HTTP server.

Answer (score 0):

That is because JSP are not HTML file. JSP are templates that generate HTML files.

Browsers display HTML files.

Tomcat is a Web Cotainer which generate HTML from JSP files. Although there is lot to it.
JSP are tranlated to there corresponding java files(Which are Servlets), Which are then compiled and instantiated usually on first call to JSP. You better start reading lifecycle of both Servlets and JSP.